# DAX running sum in custom periods Year to year

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have a table with the name of certain promotional periods and their start and end dates for the current year (every year it will be a new table with slightly different periods). I need to calculate running sum of sales between the start and end date of selected period and compare it to the same period last year and show it on a chart for comparison.

Comment: What does the period/date table look like? The periods are different each year, how do you compare them? By name, or number? Could you post a screenshot of the tables, with columns?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I've found a workaround, but it's working:
First I take just day and month from start and end dates for each period:

```
Start = FORMAT(VALUES('Promo'[start]); "dd-MM")
End = FORMAT(VALUES('Promo'[end]); "dd-MM")
```

then for the current year and for previous year I create measures used for filtering the sales:

```
Sales start = DATEVALUE([Start] & "-" & [Year])
Sales start LY = DATEVALUE([Start] & "-" & [Y-1])
Sales end = DATEVALUE([End] & "-" & [Year])
Sales end LY = DATEVALUE([End] & "-" & [Y-1])
```

and I use those dates in the running total calculation for this year and Y-1.

Now when I make a slicer with Promotional period names and select one of the periods all is being calculated correctly.

The thing I still need to solve is how to put those running totals on one chart for comparison.

Comment: What's happening when you put both measures in one chart?